# Customer specific resource files in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

I am looking for a way to extend my application to use a client specific resource file. Currently I have resource files for different cultures which is working fine. But now I want to have different resource file for each client and if I don't have client specific file then it should load the default one.

This is what I am doing currently:

App_GlobalResources
 GR.resx
 GR.ru-RU.resx

and I read resource like this

text='<%$ Resources:GR,home %>'

OR

GetGlobalResourceObject("GR","home")

This is what I want:
App_GlobalResources
GR.resx 
GR.ru-RU.resx

Client1
   GR.resx
   GR.ru-RU.resx

Client2
   GR.resx
   GR.ru-RU.resx

I do not want to change the code on my pages the way I am reading resources, is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by client?

Comment: Sorry I meant Customer... one customer may be saying "start" to "home" so that's why I want a different resource file for each customer

Comment: In theory I understand your question, but cannot imagine how it would be work from user (customer) perspective. User will have option to define own dictionary (each word) or what? As you know resources are connected to the language and culture, but it always be only one option. In your solution each user demands own dictionary but from where we should take values for the dictionary? Beacuse keys are pretty obvious

Comment: I am working on a financial application and each customer seems to be referring the terms differently from each other. Like "Profit" may be "Available Profit" , "Total Profit" or "My Profit" for some customer, so in this example my key in the resource file is "Profit" and the value would be different for each customer in their own Resource file. As my code base is same for all customers so I cannot change them in the only resource file I have in application.

Comment: Does the customer need this strings in multiple languages? Or is the language always fixed to one per user? Then I would go with some customization and not resources.

Comment: Yes, we support around 6 languages currently and each customer would like to have different languages as that customer is operating in 114 countries of the world. And we have many customers and we are pitching many more...

Comment: I think I would need to write a custom Resource Provider Model and look into customer specific directory, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Safeer, after discussion in comments I truly understand your problem. I would use following solution. Basing on your example with profits:

1. Prepare few different entries for Profit (depend on customer type or whatever):

   - key1: "Type1Profit" value: "Available Profit"
   - key2: "Type2Profit" value: "Total Profit"

Where TypeN is your customer type.

After that in view do something like this:

```
text='<%$ Resources:GR, string.Format("{0}Profit", customer.Type) %>'
```

Or

```
GetGlobalResourceObject("GR",string.Format("{0}Profit", customer.Type))
```

Thanks to this solution you should get key which you want and of course specific value for customer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I would have to change the code in many places, I'm afraid. I think I would need to write a custom Resource Provider Model and look into customer specific directory something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx