# How to customize .net resource files for different customer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization, resx

I have an asp.net mvc application which uses Resx files for different languages. The files are existing in Web project and another one service layer.

I want now to customize some labels for specific customer (they have accounts and login to our web app). Is it possible to to archive with less code change?

Have reached some articles like below but switch to use database seems require much work.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19277221/4903729
- or
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx
- or
  http://afana.me/archive/2013/11/01/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx/

It seems using a custom resource provider to load *customer based resx files* could help but the difficulty I am thinking of is:

- how to pass customerID to the resource provider.
- how to load resource dll file from custom directory like \bin\de\customer1*.resources.dll or \bin\it\customer1*.resources.dll

Comment: _have no idea on passing customerID to the resource provider_ probably you need to use UserPrincipal property in your controllers

Comment: Yes thanks @MahmoudHboubati for pointing out. Now I will see how to load customer specific resource...

Answer (score 2):

So well I have a solution working ! (based on the post from [Afana](http://afana.me/archive/2013/11/01/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx/)), code change should be very less (create xml files, run ResourceBuilder.exe).

What I did customize is just little:

- Modify the `ResourceBuilder` to generate all keys in a partial class
- Manually create Resources.provider.cs which instantiates `XmlResourceProvider` for individual customer or accepts default xml resource

[image]

- If this helps [here is the poc](https://github.com/juanonsoftware/POC/tree/master/CustomerBasedMultiLanguages) - change CustomerId / uiCulture to test.